# Grepping all strings on the same line

Tags: command-line, grep, sed, awk

Trying to find a way to grep all names on one line for 100 files. grepping all names available in each file must appear on the same line.

FILE1

```
"company":"COMPANY1","companyDisplayName":"CM1","company":"COMPANY2","companyDisplayName":"CM2","company":"COMPANY3","companyDisplayName":"CM3",
```

FILE2

```
"company":"COMPANY99","companyDisplayName":"CM99"
```

The output i actually want is, ( include file name as prefix.)

```
FILE1:COMPANY1,COMPANY2,COMPANY3    
FILE2:COMPANY99
```

i tried `grep -oP '(?<="company":")[^"]*' *` but i get results like this :

```
FILE1:COMPANY1
FILE1:COMPANY2
FILE1:COMPANY3
FILE2:COMPANY99
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using a Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE) why not use Perl itself?

```
$ perl -0777 -lnE 'say "$ARGV:", join ",", /(?<="company":")[^"]*/g' FILE*
FILE1:COMPANY1,COMPANY2,COMPANY3
FILE2:COMPANY99
```

If each file contains only a single line, you may omit the `-0777` "slurp".

Comment: Thank a lot mr @steeldriver its working fine